# How to generate dynamic import chunk name in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I am dynamically calling an import statement in my TypeScript code, based on that Webpack will create chunks like below:

[image]

You can see Webpack is automatically generating the file name as `1`, `2`, `3` respectively, the name is not a friendly name.

I have tried a way to provide the chunk name through comment, but it's generating `modulename1.bundle.js , modulename2.bundle.js`

```
bootStrapApps(config) {

    config.apps.forEach(element => {

      registerApplication(
        // Name of our single-spa application
        element.name,
        // Our loading function
        () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "modulename"*/  "../../" +
            config.rootfolder +
            "/" +
            element.name +
            "/" +

            "app.bootstrap.js"),
        // Our activity function
        () => true
      );
    });
    start();
}
```

Is there any way to specify the module name dynamically though this comment? I don't know this is specific to TypeScript or Webpack.

Comment: This is specific to Webpack and NOT related to TypeScript

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments):

> webpackChunkName: A name for the new chunk. Since webpack 2.6.0, the placeholders [index] and [request] are supported within the given string to an incremented number or the actual resolved filename respectively.

You can use `[request]` placeholder to set dynamic chunk name.
A basic example would be:

```js
const cat = "Cat";
import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
  `./animals/${cat}`
);
```

So the chunk name will be `Cat`. But if you put the string `Cat` in the path, `[request]` will throw a warning during the build saying `request was undefined`.
So this will not work:

```js
import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
  "./animals/Cat"
);
```

Finally, your code would look something like this:

```js
bootStrapApps(config) {
    config.apps.forEach((element) => {
      registerApplication(
        // Name of our single-spa application
        element.name,
        // Our loading function
        () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `../../${config.rootfolder}/${
            element.name
          }/app.bootstrap.js`),
        // Our activity function
        () => true
      );
    });
    start();
  }
```

Look at this GitHub issue for more help. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4807

PS: Those comments are called **webpack magic comments**.

Comment: This is perfect .... is there a way to lowercase the file names? Right now I'm getting `Team-Form.js` which is still WAY better than having the whole path, but lowercase would be preferred.

Comment: @VinceKronlein Not really sure if that's possible. Chunk name will be same as the file name.

Comment: Actually now with WebPack 5 you can output chunkFilename as a function and do transformations there.

```
chunkFilename: (pathData) => {
    let name = pathData.chunk.name.toLowerCase()
    pathData.chunk.name = name

    return 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `chunkFilename` in webpack config file.

It's available with `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`.

It seems to me `chunkFilename` in config is more convenient sometimes than `webpackChunkName` in each file

See details in https://medium.com/@anuhosad/code-splitting-in-webpack-with-dynamic-imports-4385b3760ef8

Comment: This is a good strategy for cache busting by adding a hash to your file, but it will not remove the file path to your files that gets generated by importing. For instance let's say your js files are located at `assets/js` and you have a Vue component called Layout. Chunking will produce the file `assets_js_Layout_vue.js` and it gets longer as you nest further. Using the magic comment with let you specify what you want the file to be named.