# Regular Expression to Exclude folder and files in Webpack Dynamic Import

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, dynamic-import

Recently i came across web pack dynamic import [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234), and manage to import via [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using webpackChunkName, following an answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339114/how-to-generate-dynamic-import-chunk-name-in-webpack).

Due to the js file that i'm importing is an app project itself, it contains the node_modules packages and some other source code files, thus webpack is packaging everything during build.

How should i only include the build folder only in my import using webpackInclude and regular expression?

Here is my import code

```
let entry = 'main.js'
let appName = 'app1'

import(
  /* webpackInclude : ./apps/*/dist */
  `./apps/${appName}/dist/${entry}`
)
```

Here is my folder structure in brief

```
|-- apps
  |-- app1
    |-- dist
      |-- main.js
    |-- node_modules
    |-- src
    |-- package.json
    |-- webpack.config.js
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
|-- webpack.config.js
```

The import code is at app.js, would need help to correct `./apps/*/dist` to a correct regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Add slashes at the beginning and end of regex, and necessary character escapes. Your regex needs to care only about the variable portions (ie: starting from ${appName}, do not worry about `./apps/`)

an example to match js files would be:

```js
import(
  /* webpackInclude: /[^\/]+\/dist\/.+\.js/ */
  `./apps/${appName}/dist/${entry}`
)
```

explanation of regex here: https://regex101.com/r/F6XlIQ/1
(hover of parts of it)

learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions