# No response even if img path is specified on React APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I Launch project with create-react-app. No response even if img path is specified on React APP.
Image is displayed when import statement is used

```
// not working (1)
<img src={"../img/hoge.png"} />;

//working (2)
import Hoge from "../img/hoge.png";

<img src={Hoge} />
```

I want to user pattern　(1).
Please tell me the solution orz......

Comment: I don't think the first way is possible. I think the reason is that Webpack needs the imports at the top of each file in order to work correctly. But someone else may have more information.

Comment: Why do you want to use solution 1 instead of 2? Solution 2 is what is supported by create-react-app and webpack out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Use `require` for dynamic imports, path like `"../img/hoge.png"` is **not available in runtime** because Webpack generates [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in build time.

```
import hoge from '../img/hoge.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image
console.log(hoge); // /hoge.84287d09.png

// For dynamic imports
<img src={require("../img/hoge.png")}  />
```

See Adding images in [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of potential images at build time, you can use the dynamic `import` function to load them, although this will return a promise like so:

```
export class ImageLoader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imagePath: undefined
        };
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.imagePath)
            return <img src={this.state.imagePath}  />; // Render the image
        import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */`../imgs/${this.props.imageName}.png`) // Bundle all paths of images into the bundle
            .then((imagePath: string) => {
                this.setState({ imagePath}); // Set the new state with the loaded image path
            });
        return null; // Don't render anything right now since the image hasn't loaded yet.
    }
}
```

This will bundle ALL png images under the imgs directory, use a `switch` statement with all possible names if that is too much.

See [Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) and [How does Dynamic Import in webpack works when used with an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995331/how-does-dynamic-import-in-webpack-works-when-used-with-an-expression)