# Is it possible to inject a variable value into a javascript comment?

Tags: javascript, webpack, comments, react-lazy-load

**TL;DR:** is it possible to inject constant variables (that won't change during runtime) in comments

I've come across a very unique situation where I need my comments to have a specific value in them.

I'm code splitting in React and the way to name chunks in react is to add comment next to the import like this:

```
const MyComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('./MyComponent' /* webpackChunkName: "MyComponent" */)
)
```

This gives my lazy loaded chunks readable names over generated id names.

There's a section in my codebase where I generate lazy loaded routes for my components based on my folder structure, but I've hit a wall where I can't set my chunk name to a variable set by a function.

Here's my function:

```
function generateLink(label: string) {
  const path = label.replaceAll(' ', '');
  return {
    Element: lazy(
      () => import(`./pages/${path}`, /* webpackChunkName: "{{this should be path}}" */)
    ),
    label,
    path
  };

}
```

Is there anyway for me to inject the `path` variable into that comment?

An extra side note, this `generateLink` function is not run during runtime, the links are static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no simple method for injecting variables into your comments. However, there is a webpack solution to your specific problem, just use [Magic Comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)

Updating your `generateLink` function to the following should resolve your problem.

```
function generateLink(label: string) {
  const path = label.replaceAll(' ', '');
  return {
    Element: lazy(
      () => import(`./pages/${path}`, /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */)
    ),
    label,
    path
  };
}
```

Now if your `path` is `HomePage`, your chunk name will resolve to `/HomePage.[chunkId].js`

Just make sure that all your file names are unique, otherwise webpack will suffix a number to your chunks for non-unique file names.

E.g. if you have 2 file names of `HomePage.jsx`, then you will end up with `/HomePage0.[chunkId].js` and `/HomePage2.[chunkId].js`

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered before in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345836/2188587

You can use a placeholder `[request]` and webpack will automatically use the resolved file name.

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `./pages/${path}`)
```

I checked the docs, it still exists.

Exception: It will use the file name, so if you have nested files and `path` variable can also use directories, you're probably out of luck.